# Tuples in Sparql

Tags: tuples, sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web

if a subject/object get multiple values in sparql, is there any way to get those values to utilize those multiple values in query. For example a city has weather conditions. after running query we got multiple values in our subject/object.Now how shall we utilize these values or assign specific values to each of them.

I want to get results like when I query for: `Lahore has Weather Conditions` (i.e query should give me all weather conditions with their assigned values.) Assigned values means that I've assigned individuals some value using data property. I just want to know that is there any way to get all weather conditions of Lahore with their hard coded values. as shown in this example:

[image]

I'm attaching snapshots of my ontology. Hope it will create more understanding to you.

1. Classes and Individuals.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tR2l.png]

2. Object Properties (Domain Range of WeatherConditions) :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecqcs.png]

3. Data property and Domain Ranges (hasDewpoint and all instances of Weather Condition have same Domain but diff values)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAqVs.png]

4. Let's take example for City Lahore. it has characteristics:

[image]

Comment: In other word, I want to get triple result indexes. as working on any programming language we assign values to array and then we can utilize it by using index number.

Comment: Hi @hassan-syed, welcome to StackOverflow! It's not very clear what you're asking, exactly. Can you please [edit] your question to add an example of an actual SPARQL query, the result that it gets back, and example of a result that you _want_ to get? Please have a look at [ask], which contains many good tips on how to make your question better.

Comment: It looks more like he's asking for indexing resp. dictionary encoding in combination with vertical partitioning. But strangely, this time after the query has been executed. Or does he really just want to assign a number per tuple of the resutset? @HassanSyed can you explain more the *what* and *why*? Maybe, give a small example.

Comment: Let me try to explain one more time. I'm attaching snapshots of my ontology. Hope it will create more understanding to you. 1. Classes and Individuals. Fig 1: i.stack.imgur.com/4tR2l.png 2. Object Properties (Domain Range of WeatherConditions) Fid 2: i.stack.imgur.com/ecqcs.png 3.Data property and Domain Ranges (hasDewpoint and all instances of Weather Condition have same Domain but diff values) Fig 3: i.stack.imgur.com/SAqVs.png 4. Let's take example for City Lahore. it has characteristics Fig 4: i.stack.imgur.com/X6oHk.png Sorry I'm new at semantic.

Comment: I want to get results like when i query for: Lahore has Weather Conditions (i.e query should give me all weather conditions with their assigned values.) 
i.e
assigned values means that i've assigned individuals some value using data property. I just want to know that is there any way to get all weather conditions of Lahore with their hard coded values.
as shown in sample Fig 5. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cLZ1.png

Thanks for your support! –

Comment: @HassanSyed please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. It makes things clearer and allows for better formatting.

Comment: I've done the editing for you this time around. To be honest it's still not fully clear to me what you're after or where you're stuck. You haven't shown any SPARQL query. What's also not clear from the many screenshot is _how_ these "hardcoded values" are linked to the individual `Lahore`. I can see it has multiple `WeatherCondition` instances linked, one of which is, say, `Temperature`. But where is the actual value `5` (the value of the temperature you say you want back) in your data?